# can I upload photo to server through android's photo gallery with titanium appcelerator?

Tags: android, titanium, photo, photo-upload

I have asked this question on appcelerator forum but no reply. I have also tried to upload photo with photo gallery but failed. Can someone please tell me whether uploading photo through photo gallery in android is supported by titanium? Thanks.

Comment: what does your server code look like? uploading the image is a simple http POST to your server

Comment: my server code is in php, using $_FILES. Do you means that I can upload image in Android's photo gallery?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any real official documentation on the subject but according to this. https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/camera.js

```
var data = [
    {title:'Camera Basic', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/camera_basic.js'}
];

if (Ti.Platform.osname == "iphone") {
    data.push({title:'Camera Custom Overlay', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/camera_overlay.js'});
    data.push({title:'Camera Overlay Webview', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/camera_overlay_webview.js'});
    data.push({title:'Camera Augmented Reality', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/camera_ar.js'});
    data.push({title:'Save to Gallery (Auto)', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/camera_gallery.js'});
    data.push({title:'Save to File', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/camera_file.js'});    

    Ti.include('version.js');

    if (isiOS4Plus()) {
        data.push({title:'Video Record', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/camera_video.js'});   

        //TODO: this seems to work the first time, but not subsequent. fix for 1.5
        //data.push({title:'Video Editing', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/video_edit.js'});  
    }
}
```

It seems that all working Camera functions including the save to file is set to `iphone`

However have you read up on this page and tried this https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/xhr_fileupload.js